# AWS lex integration to slack issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, slack, slack-api, aws-lib

I have recently created the AWS lex bot tested in AWS lex console working very well, then integrated the same in the slack and Twilio

it's working very well in Twilio but in slack it is only responding to me not to others.

Any help would be really appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Other's should select the bit you created. When somebody trying to communicate to you in Lex they will have the normal IM window and the bot you created. If they IM to normal one it will not respond to your Lex bot